# How to inflate the XML layout using Custom ArrayAdapter Class?

Tags: java, android, listview

In my app,I need to have delete button in my listview,So to do that I refer this link [ListView with Add and Delete Buttons in each Row in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525886/listview-with-add-and-delete-buttons-in-each-row-in-android).

I refer the first answer,but the problem now is,in that they are adding items to the listview like this.

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("item1");
    list.add("item2");
```

But ,I fetch data to listview using cursor.Below one is my code to fetch data from database to listview.

```
 private void fetchData() {
        db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query(DBhelper.TABLE1, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.row,
                c,
                new String[]{DBhelper.Name},
                new int[]{R.id.lblreload});
        rldlist.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Now I don't have any idea,how to modify that code.please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `CursorAdapter` and provide implementations for `newView()` and `bindView()`.

Comment: @xyz Any competent search engine will find this for you.

Comment: okey,so Do I need to create separate for that,how can I call it back here