# Custom Listview with Text and two Images

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-viewholder

I am new to Android Development and I am making an application in which I have an EditText and below EditText there is submit Button.
I want that when I write something in EditText and then click submit, the Edittext value will show in Listview with pre defined two Images i.e. their is EditText value in listview and on the right of it two Images also added with that Submit button. These images are Delete and Edit Images so that whenever i click on delete it delete that item and whenever i click on Edit image the EditText value will be ready for editing.
I know that this will be done by getView method and a holder but i could not find any best example for that.
Can anyone provide me the best example for holder and custom listview regarding my application?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for help with. Instead of assuming StackOverflow users will provide the entire code for you, please provide some code of what you have already tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525886/listview-with-add-and-delete-buttons-in-each-row-in-android