# Using button in custom listview

Tags: android, listview

in my android project I am using a custom listview where all the values are retrieved from the server and displayed in the listview. I have a button along with the textview in the listview entries, now I want to functionality of the button to be like when I click it will take the value from any textview of the same group and display it in the alert box. I retrieved the data and displayed successfully but I'm not able crack how to use the button to get the textview values of the list.. Thanks in advance for any help... My codes are posted below.

This is my contact adapter class:

```
package com.example.sohan.doctor;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Sohan on 6/9/2016.
 */
public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    notification nt = new notification();
    List list = new ArrayList();
    View row;
    ContactHolder contactHolder;
    public ContactAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }


    public void add(List<Contacts> updatedList) {
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(updatedList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        row = convertView;

        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_symptom_layout,parent,false);
            contactHolder = new ContactHolder();
            contactHolder.Name =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            contactHolder.Age =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            contactHolder.Height =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            contactHolder.Weight =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            contactHolder.Symptom =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
            contactHolder.button = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button3);
            contactHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String name;
                    name = nt.newList.get(position).getName(); // This is where I'm stucked.
                    Toast.makeText(getContext().getApplicationContext(), name+" is served ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            row.setTag(contactHolder);
        }
        else{

            contactHolder = (ContactHolder)row.getTag();
        }



        Contacts contacts = (Contacts)this.getItem(position);
        contactHolder.Name.setText("Name: "+contacts.getName());
        contactHolder.Age.setText("Age: "+contacts.getAge());
        contactHolder.Height.setText("Height: "+contacts.getHeight());
        contactHolder.Weight.setText("Weight: "+contacts.getWeight());
        contactHolder.Symptom.setText("Symptoms: "+contacts.getSymptom());
        return row;



    }

    static class ContactHolder{
        TextView Name;
        TextView Age;
        TextView Height;
        TextView Weight;
        TextView Symptom;
        Button button;
    }

}
```

And this is the class where I retrieve all the values from server and store it in listview:

```
package com.example.sohan.doctor;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Sohan on 6/25/2016.
 */
public class notification extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    public final static String Message = "Sohan";
    View myView;
    String selectedCity;
    Context myContext;
    String jsonResult;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    String JSON_String;
    ContactAdapter contactAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    List<Contacts> newList;
    Button button;
    String send;
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification, container, false);
        myContext = inflater.getContext();
        contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(myContext, R.layout.view_symptom_layout);
        listView = (ListView)myView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
        retrieveInfo ri = new retrieveInfo();
        ri.execute();
        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }


    class retrieveInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {             // send data to server

        String myUrl;


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            myUrl ="httP://myserver.com";    // change php script
        }


        protected String doInBackground(Void... args) {
            String city;
            String result = null;
            JSONArray jsonArray = null;
            try{
                URL url = new URL(myUrl);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
               // String data_to_send = URLEncoder.encode("city", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(city,"UTF-8");
                //bufferedWriter.write(data_to_send);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


                while ((JSON_String = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(JSON_String+"\n");
                }
                reader.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                is.close();
                return sb.toString().trim();
            }catch(MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException f){
                f.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            jsonResult = result;
            parseJSON(jsonResult);
        }
    }


    public void parseJSON(String json){
        Contacts contacts=null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("patient");
            int count = 0;
            String name,age,height,weight,symptom;
            newList = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
            while (count < jsonArray.length()) {
                JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                name = jo.getString("Name");                          // data's are send to store in and print in listview
                age = jo.getString("Age");
                height = jo.getString("Height");
                weight = jo.getString("Weight");
                symptom = jo.getString("Symptom");
                contacts = new Contacts(name,age,height,weight,symptom);

                newList.add(contacts);                                   // data are stored in the newlist array
                count++;
            }

            contactAdapter.add(newList);                               // the newlist array are send to add in the listview

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the toast displaying?

Comment: Toast displaying some blaberish references..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make some more changes like following.

```
ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contacts>
List<Contacts> list = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
```

And this line:

```
String name,age,height,weight,symptom;
```

You should put in while loop with initialize as null `""`

Comment: You know you can just edit your original answer. There's a link below it, to the left.

Comment: It worked but it can retrieve value from just first 3 rows, from the 4th row it is again showing the value of the first 3 rows, is there any issues regarding length of the list??

Comment: I think instead of using this "contactAdapter.add(newList)", you don't need to use "add()" function like this, 

You can add a parameter to ContactAdapter constructor, ex: List<Contacts>. And then in the main activity, you just pass "newList" to the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = nt.newList.get(position).getName();
```

I think it should be:

```
name = list.get(position).getName();
```

You cam also read this article:
[ListView with Add and Delete Buttons in each Row in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525886/listview-with-add-and-delete-buttons-in-each-row-in-android)