# How to make views visible per button click

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an app that does some calculation. It consists of a horizontal `linearLayout` and each Layout has 2 edit text and and a spinner. I want to make it in such a way that the user can add layouts with button click when he needs to add more details.

In my XML I set `android:visibility="gone"` and in Java I set the `onClick` method to make the "gone" linear layout to `view.VISIBLE`. It worked but it makes all the linear layouts appear once I click the + button. I want them to appear one after the other (one appear and others remain "gone" until I click the button again)

Comment: Use a full stop (period) every once in a while. The word is _button_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Layout inflater.

create another resource file in which add layout and widgets which you required
e.g item_resource.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

  <!-- other layout elements which are required -->

</LinearLayout>
```

then inflate above layout pragmatically on onClick event

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  View view = inflater .inflate(R.layout.item_resource,null);
  Button button =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
  button.setText("  ");   // set value
```

Add this view to your main layout
e.g

```
 LinearLayout myLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.xx);
 mylayout.add(view);
```

Comment: It worked for only one click, but if i click the button again it doesn't add. I want it to be in such a way that it adds layout on each button click. Thank you.

Comment: if you want add new view on button click then use RecycleView and custom Adapter. Add new item to RecyleView on button click by overriding getView () method of custom adapter

Comment: Can you help me with a sample code please.  Thank you.

Comment: Hope this will help you [ this ] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525886/listview-with-add-and-delete-buttons-in-each-row-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use fragments for this situation. you can add any fragments to view via an events.

Comment: I am new to android more details please

Comment: A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).