# set onClickListener on Imageview(Listview) inside activity

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

Is there a way to set onClickListener on Imageview(Listview) inside activity ?
I'v created this , and it works just fine in my adapter, But it's not working in my activity :

```
    @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    playPause=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.playPause); 
     Product m = productList.get(position);
     playPause.setImageResource(m.getPlayPauseId());
     playPause.setTag(position);
     playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
                 int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                 Product m =productList.get(pos);
                 if (paused) {
                 m.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                 paused=false;
                 }else {
                  m.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
                  paused = true;
                }    
                 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });

    }
```

**And this is my Product class :**

```
public class Product implements Serializable {

private int PlayPauseId;

@SerializedName("pid")
public int pid;

@SerializedName("name")
public String name;

@SerializedName("qty")
public int qty;

@SerializedName("price")
public String description;

@SerializedName("image_url")
public String image_url;

@SerializedName("date")
public String date;



public int getPlayPauseId() {
    return PlayPauseId;
}

public void setPlayPauseId(int playPauseId) {
    PlayPauseId = playPauseId;
        }

  }
```

**Adapter Class (Fundapter library) :**

```
public class FunDapter<T> extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

protected List<T> mDataItems;
protected List<T> mOrigDataItems;
protected LongExtractor<T> idExtractor;
protected final Context mContext;
private final int mLayoutResource;
private final BindDictionary<T> mBindDictionary;
private int oddColorRes;
private int evenColorRes;
private FunDapterFilter<T> funDapterFilter;
private Filter mFilter;



public FunDapter(Context context, List<T> dataItems, int layoutResource,
                 BindDictionary<T> dictionary) {
  this(context, dataItems, layoutResource, null, dictionary);
}


public FunDapter(Context context, List<T> dataItems, int layoutResource,
                 LongExtractor<T> idExtractor, BindDictionary<T> dictionary) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mDataItems = dataItems;
    this.mOrigDataItems = dataItems;
    this.mLayoutResource = layoutResource;
    this.idExtractor = idExtractor;
    this.mBindDictionary = dictionary;

}


public void updateData(List<T> dataItems) {
    this.mDataItems = dataItems;
    this.mOrigDataItems = dataItems;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (mDataItems == null || mBindDictionary == null) return 0;

    return mDataItems.size();
}

@Override
public T getItem(int position) {
    return mDataItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    if(idExtractor == null) return super.hasStableIds();
    else return true;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    if(idExtractor == null) return position;
    else return idExtractor.getLongValue(getItem(position), position);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    View v = convertView;
    final GenericViewHolder holder;
    if (null == v) {
        LayoutInflater vi =
                (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(mLayoutResource, null);
        holder = new GenericViewHolder();
        holder.root = v;





        FunDapterUtils.initViews(v, holder, mBindDictionary);

        v.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (GenericViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }



    final T item = getItem(position);
    showData(item, holder, position);




    return v;
}
```

Comment: you can set it in getView method of your adapter class. above won't work as you are setting on click, on click of item of listview.

Comment: I think remove onItemClick and directly set click of imageview in onBindViewHolder in adapter

Comment: @JunaidHafeez I knew that it may not work .. but i insist to do this in my activity

Comment: send your full adapter code

Comment: @ZakiPathan can't set it directly cause i don't know how to get the position then .. and i already said that it works in my adapter.

Comment: @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {}  you can get position here. hope you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with two ways:
Make an interface something like this

```
public interface ImageClick {
   public imageButtonOnClick(View view, int position)
}
```

implement it in your activity, and in your adapter `getView`, set `imageOnClickListener`, and call this interface method inside that `onClick`, pass your position and view in it, so you can use position etc in your activity callback.

Second is to just make a method in your activity like in interface

```
public imageButtonOnClick(View view, int position)
```

in your adapter onClick method on imageView, call it something like

```
((YourActivity)context).imageButtonOnClick(params1, param2);
```

Comment: It seems your solution will work ,as I am new in android can you kindly explain more your way "one" with an example !?, i will accept your answer

Comment: before i edit and put details, i have found a good example exactly what I am saying. see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27716788 let me know if you still need any help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Custom your ArrayAdapter and set action in method getView

See this page

[ListView with Add and Delete Buttons in each Row in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525886/listview-with-add-and-delete-buttons-in-each-row-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

For getting click the image in the list view in the activity itself you have to callback

Create an interface

```
public interface OnButtonClickListener {
public void onButtonClick(int position,View view);

}
```

in your actvity class implement **OnButtonClickListener**

you get a interface methood

```
@Override
public void onButtonClick(final int position, View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.YOURIMAGEVIEWID:
       //implent your process...
  }
}
```

Create constructor in adapter calss

```
 Context context;
 OnButtonClickListener callback
 public AdapterClass(Context context OnButtonClickListener buttonClickListener) {
    this.context = context;
    callback = buttonClickListener;
}
```

image click in adapter class

```
holder.imageView..setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            callback.onButtonClick(position, v);
        }
    });
```

in your actvity class

```
 AdapterClass Adapter = new AdapterClass(youractivity.this, youractivity.this);
```

Add this class for callback

```
public class ListCustomClickEvents implements OnClickListener,View.OnTouchListener {
private int position;
private OnCustomClickListener callback;


// Pass in the callback (this'll be the activity) and the row position
public ListCustomClickEvents(OnCustomClickListener callback, int pos) {
    position = pos;
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    callback.OnCustomClick(v, position);
}
}
```