# How to add two buttons in listview

Tags: android

I would like to add two buttons in my listview.
Two button edit and delete for my list.
I have already traveled the other posts on this subject but I still can not :(.
I have already created a custom listview.
I am a beginner so I have a hard time understanding.
This would be nice a little help.
Here is my code

My current listview

```
public class liste_offre extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper myDb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.liste_offre);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List_offre);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
    if (res.getCount()==0){
        Toast.makeText(liste_offre.this,"Liste vide",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        while (res.moveToNext()){
            theList.add(res.getString(1));
            ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theList);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: add two buttons where? to every list item? or just two buttons outside of listview, some where in layout?

Comment: Two buttons to each item in the list

Comment: Then you should not use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` and need to create a custom adapter which extends, for example, `BaseAdapter`. Look for the tutorial in the web

Comment: I will work on it and I will tell you if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the below post it may be exactly what you want

[ListView with Add and Delete Buttons in each Row in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525886/listview-with-add-and-delete-buttons-in-each-row-in-android)

Hope this helps you.