# Adding button to custom ListView Adapter

Tags: android, listview

I am using following method to populate a listview inside a fragment class.

```
private void showEmployee(){
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

            for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String cia = jo.getString(Config.TAG_CIA);
                String fn = jo.getString(Config.TAG_FN);
                String ln = jo.getString(Config.TAG_LN);
                String ad1 = jo.getString(Config.TAG_AD1);
                String ad2 = jo.getString(Config.TAG_AD2);
                String type = jo.getString(Config.TAG_TYPE);
                String city = jo.getString(Config.TAG_CITY);
                String state = jo.getString(Config.TAG_STATE);
                String zip = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ZIP);

                String phone = jo.getString(Config.TAG_PHONE);

                String ext = jo.getString(Config.TAG_EXT);

                String fromto = jo.getString(Config.TAG_FROMTO);

                Log.d("HOLA ADDRESSES", "FROM O TO: " + fromto);


                String user = jo.getString(Config.TAG_USER);


                String id_address = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ID_ADDRESS);


                HashMap<String,String> employees = new HashMap<>();
                employees.put(Config.TAG_CIA,cia);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_LN,fn);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_FN,ln);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_AD1,ad1);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_AD2,ad2);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_TYPE,type);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_CITY,city);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_STATE,state);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_ZIP,zip);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_PHONE,phone);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_EXT,ext);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_FROMTO,fromto);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_USER,user);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_ID_ADDRESS,id_address);



                list.add(employees);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(), list, R.layout.addresses_list_item,
                new String[]{Config.TAG_CIA,
                        Config.TAG_FN,
                        Config.TAG_LN,
                        Config.TAG_AD1,
                        Config.TAG_AD2,
                        Config.TAG_TYPE,
                        Config.TAG_CITY,
                        Config.TAG_STATE,
                        Config.TAG_ZIP,
                        Config.TAG_PHONE,
                        Config.TAG_EXT,
                        Config.TAG_FROMTO,
                        Config.TAG_USER,
                        Config.TAG_ID_ADDRESS},
                new int[]{R.id.cia,
                        R.id.fn,
                        R.id.ln,
                        R.id.ad1,
                        R.id.ad2,
                        R.id.type,
                        R.id.city,
                        R.id.state,
                        R.id.zip,
                        R.id.phone,
                        R.id.ext,
                        R.id.fromto,
                        R.id.user,
                        R.id.id_address});

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Now I want to include a button on every row from the list and be able to change the button text on every row depending on the value from one of the items.

I have included the button inside the listview item layout file.

I don´t know where to put the button reference on this method.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to use custom adapters for this, make custom adapter, have the reference for the button there, and have onClickListener on button

Comment: @AbdulKawee, would you help me creating the custom adapter based on my currend code?

Comment: Yes sure, i can share the code with you and you will understand it easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a `model` for your data

```
public class DataModel {

    String title;
    String description;
    String addedby;

    public DataModel(String title, String description, String addedby) {
        this.title=title;
        this.description=description;
        this.addedby=addedby;

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getAddedby() {
        return addedby;
    }


}
```

Then define custom adapter for your list

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements View.OnClickListener{

```
private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;
Context mContext;

// View lookup cache
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    TextView description;
    TextView addedBy;
Button yourButton;

}

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_view_items, data);
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mContext=context;

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int position=(Integer) v.getTag();
        Object object= getItem(position);
        DataModel dataModel=(DataModel)object;

    }

    private int lastPosition = -1;

    @Override
    public DataModel getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        final DataModel dataModel = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_items, parent, false);
            viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            viewHolder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            viewHolder.addedBy = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addedBy);
        viewholder.yourButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
            result=convertView;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result=convertView;
        }


        lastPosition = position;

        viewHolder.title.setText(dataModel.getTitle());
        viewHolder.description.setText(dataModel.getDescription());
        viewHolder.addedBy.setText(dataModel.getAddedby());
    viewholder.yourButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        // Return the completed view to render on screen

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Now the layout for your list items

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"

            android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/title"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#212121"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:id="@+id/description"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/addedBy"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textColor="#212121"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Now simply use these classes

```
  ArrayList<DataModel> dataModels;
        private static CustomAdapter adapter;

JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
            String cia = jo.getString(Config.TAG_CIA);
            String fn = jo.getString(Config.TAG_FN);
            String ln = jo.getString(Config.TAG_LN);
 dataModels.add(new DataModel(cia , fn , ln ));
 adapter= new CustomAdapter(dataModels,getApplicationContext());

            list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Comment: I am getting error at method in CustomAdapter; @Override
    public DataModel getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    } Incompatible types

Comment: Abdul, I am having problems implementing your code from the last group into my code.

Comment: It might be because you are entering data from you already made hashmaps use arraylist of data type data model

Answer (score 0):

You should create custom adapter.
Try below link :-

http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for this is to have to use custom adpter. Like this

```
public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.RecyclerViewViewHolder>  {

    private ContactAdapter.RecyclerViewViewHolder viewHolder;
    private View view;
    Context ctx;
    List<Contact> usersList;

    public ContactAdapter(Context ctx, List<Contact> usersList) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.usersList = usersList;
    }

    @Override
    public ContactAdapter.RecyclerViewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_contact_list, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new RecyclerViewViewHolder(view);
        viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewViewHolder holder, int position) {
        viewHolder.name.setText(usersList.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.avatar.setImageBitmap(AppUtil.getCircleBitmap(usersList.get(position).getAvatar()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return usersList.size();
    }

    public class RecyclerViewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView name;
        Button avatar;

        public RecyclerViewViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            avatar = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
            avatar.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = getLayoutPosition();
            Intent intent = new Intent(ctx,DetailScreen.class);
            AppUtil.hideKeyBoard(ctx);
            intent.putExtra("id",usersList.get(position).getId());
            ctx.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create a custom adapter class and in getView method you should reference the button and set on click listener on that button.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        //do something
    }
});
```

refer to this link for more details
[ListView with Add and Delete Buttons in each Row in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525886/listview-with-add-and-delete-buttons-in-each-row-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use Base Adapter for it and in getView code like this:

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        //use convertView recycle
        if(convertView==null){
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.content_orders, parent, false);
            holder.textView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.imageView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
    holder.clickableButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

                @Override  
                public void onClick(View v) {  
                   //Code goes here

                }  
            });  

        //set text and url
        holder.textView.setText(mList.get(position).getText());
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mList.get(position).getUrl()).resize(500,500).into(holder.imageView);

        return convertView;
    }
```