# Adding a clickable button to a listview item

Tags: android, listview, clickable

i am trying to add a phone button to a city guide app, where there should be a phone icon in each item that when clicked will redirect me to the dialer app with the phone number already be written.

this is the main activity code

```
public class Resto extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_resto);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ListView lv;
    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    String[] names= {"L'olivo verde","Lounge36","Punto Alto","Sa7se7", "Maison Jabbour", "Pizza Napoli", "Capri","Classic burger joint","kaakunada","Ichiban Express","Ikura Sushi","Machos" };
    int[] imageids = {R.drawable.lolivo,R.drawable.lounge,R.drawable.punto,R.drawable.sahseh, R.drawable.jabbour, R.drawable.napoli, R.drawable.capri,R.drawable.cbj, R.drawable.kaak, R.drawable.ichiban, R.drawable.ikura,R.drawable.machos, R.drawable.gate};

    lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this,names,imageids));



    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

and this is the customAdapter code

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

String[] result;
Context context; 
int[] image ID; 
LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public CustomAdapter(Context c, String[] names, int[] imageids)
{
    result = names;
    context= c;
    imageID = imageids;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return result.length;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

public class Holder {
    TextView tv;
    ImageView img;

}

public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    // i is the position. starts at 0 and keeps on incremeting till the end of the data

    Holder holder= new Holder();
    final View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.restos,null);
    holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    holder.img= (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
   holder.img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageclick);
    holder.tv.setText(result[i]);
    holder.img.setImageResource(imageID[i]);
    rowView.setTag(i);
    rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "position " + rowView.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: You have to create custom listview for this purpose. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525886/listview-with-add-and-delete-buttons-in-each-row-in-android

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First , you have to create a custom listview as mentioned by @Sahdeep Singh in the comment. Then, you have to put this code in the item onclick method:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){   
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){
        ItemClicked item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
    startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

For details, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11699829/5590249) answer. Hope this helps.